# ssp.net MVC4 controller in group

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I want to group some controller in a parent in MCV4 ASP.NET
like:

---

A- admin area

Admin/Language/(add-edit-delete-...)

Admin/User/(add-edit-delete-...)

Admin/Product/(add-edit-delete-...)

Admin/Message/(add-edit-delete-...)

(20 more)

---

B- user area

Language/(select-list-...)

User/(withdraw-charge-...)

Product/(select-top-...)

Message/(send-inbox-...)

(16 more)

---

I tryed to move controller class and view files to a sub directory named 'Admin' but when I lunch the project only 404 error page showed for "{site}/admin/language/List"

There is many controllers and I just write few of theme.
So I need to group theme for management.

My question is How to make a good and usable structure for my site?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to separate the into [areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just moving the controllers to a sub folder wont create the necessary routes to redirect the user.  You can either setup the necessary routes in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

OR

You could create a new "Area".  Right click on your MVC4 project -> Add -> Area

Then name your Area "Admin" and move your controllers / views under the Area/Admin folder.  Creating an area this way should automatically create the necessary routes in Area/Admin/AdminAreaRegistration.cs.